# Continue kerning at tag boundaries

Tags: html, css, kerning

I've got an application that uses the `<mark>` tag to interactively highlight text. As the user drags the mouse, it wraps and unwraps the text nodes in the document to show the user the selection. When the selected range ends in the middle of a word, the mark surrounds just part of the word. If the boundary is between a kerned pair, the kerning is disabled.

Here's an example:

```css
p { font-size: 30pt; margin: 0; line-height: 26pt; }
```

```html
<p>There <mark>are 1</mark>1 entries.</p>
<p>There are 11 entries.</p>
```

In the first paragraph, the <mark> tag ends between the two "1" digits. The second paragraph has the same text, without the <mark>. The font size, margin, and line-spacing are adjusted to bring the paragraphs closer together to make the differences more visible.

There's more space between the 1s with the <mark> than without. Since this happens interactively in the application, as the user drags the mouse over the 1s, the subsequent text shifts to the right when they're between the 1s and then back when they get past the next character. The "jiggling" of the text can be annoying.

Is there any way to tell the browser *not* to treat the mark tags as a kerning boundary? Maybe a font-feature-setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can turn off kerning altogether... I think that's the closest you're going to get to not seeing the effect, since the kerning boundary will always be at the tag boundary.

```css
p { font-size: 30pt; margin: 0; line-height: 26pt; font-kerning: none; }
mark { margin: 0; font-kerning: none; }
```

```html
<p>There <mark>are 1</mark>1 entries.</p>
<p>There are 11 entries.</p>
```

Comment: I suspect you're right that this will be the best I can do. I was hoping that maybe there'd be one of those less well-known CSS properties (like font-feature-setting, which has a bazillion little complicated options) that would tell the browser to ignore the boundary for the purposes of kerning.

It's clear the browser can _do_ this, since the browser's own highlighting does it (use your mouse to select the same area that's marked in the example, no change in the kerning), so I figured I'd reach out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `::selection` pseudo-element to control the highlighting of selected text.

If you want to then insert your `mark` tags, you can do that after the selection process is finished. At that point you will lose kerning at tag boundaries, but at least you won't see the jiggle as the user selects.

```css
::selection {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
There are 11 entries.<br/>
There are 11 entries.
```

Comment: That won't work in this case. There is no selected text (in that sense), so the ::selection pseudo-element doesn't refer to anything in my case.

Comment: I'm confused. When the user drags the mouse, the text is indeed selected, and the `::selection` pseudo-element does indeed refer to that selected text. Can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: I'm working on a mobile environment -- iOS, in particular. Selections don't work that way -- the user has to touch and hold, then move the resulting "handles". I need a simpler interaction for selecting text, so I'm building one.

Comment: Even on the desktop, the `::selection` doesn't necessarily apply -- in my particular application, because I'm trying to replace the built-in selection with my own, I call `preventDefault()` on the `mousemove` events. That prevents the browser from updating the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching over and over for "cleans" fixes about it but I've only figure out one way with `margin` property.

[Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/qkex1vjL/6/)

```
mark { margin: 0 -1pt; }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is not what kerning means. Kerning relates to specific character pairs.

Comment: You learn me something, I didn't know `font-kerning` property !